# Is it possible to parameterize Post requests payload and then encode it to base64 in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, base64

The background is that I want to make a REST to Google pub/sub. Where the data need to follow this format:

[Link to documentation of Pub/Sub format](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish)

My current solution is that I uses an BeanShell PreProcessor script to encode the payload to base64 before I send the request to the endpoint. This solution works, but I would like to
parameterize the data in the payload, instead of having the whole payload inserted as test data in the csv-file.

**BeanShell PreProcessor used to encode the message before it is being sent:**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.Base64Encoder;

String csv_payload = vars.get("csv_payload");
String csv_payload_encoded = Base64Encoder.encode(csv_payload);
vars.put("csv_payload_encoded", csv_payload_encoded);
```

**Payload populated from the csv-file in Post request:**

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "data":"${csv_payload_encoded}",
          }
      ]
    }
```

**Example of payload data stored in the csv-file that is sent in the request:**

```
{"identId":"123456","requestId":null,"payload":{"header":{"requestid":1,"timeStamp":1617873956,"version":"0.0.0.1","eventId":0001,"creatorId":0,"messageTTL":34560},"body":{"checkid":001,"checkData":{"diagnosticsData":{"troubleSource":0,"data":"[2020-01-01 16:00:53.707961][[lat[0]][long[0]][alt[0]][canbetrust[0]][mars[0]]][signal[5]][TEM2 wake up]"}}}}}
```

**Example of the encoded payload that the request sends to google pub/sub:**

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "data":"eyJpZGVudElkIjoiMTIzNDU2IiwicmVxdWVzdElkIjpudWxsLCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImhlYWRlciI6eyJyZXF1ZXN0aWQiOjEsInRpbWVTdGFtcCI6MTYxNzg3Mzk1NiwidmVyc2lvbiI6IjAuMC4wLjEiLCJldmVudElkIjowMDAxLCJjcmVhdG9ySWQiOjAsIm1lc3NhZ2VUVEwiOjM0NTYwfSwiYm9keSI6eyJjaGVja2lkIjowMDEsImNoZWNrRGF0YSI6eyJkaWFnbm9zdGljc0RhdGEiOnsidHJvdWJsZVNvdXJjZSI6MCwiZGF0YSI6IlsyMDIwLTAxLTAxIDE2OjAwOjUzLjcwNzk2MV1bW2xhdFswXV1bbG9uZ1swXV1bYWx0WzBdXVtjYW5iZXRydXN0WzBdXVttYXJzWzBdXV1bc2lnbmFsWzVdXVtURU0yIHdha2UgdXBdIn19fX19",
          }
      ]
    }
```

If there are any feedback I would appreciate it or any other improvements suggestion
for how I would be able to proceed in order to parameterize and encode the payload to base64 eg:

[Example of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz6uJ.png)

Comment: I solved this by adding an user defined variables before my test containing a parameter "payload_before_encoding" with the
"{"identId":"${example}","requestId":null,"payload":{"header":{"requestid":1,"timeStamp":1617873956,"version":"0.0.0.1","eventId":0001,"creatorId":0,"messageTTL":34560},"body":{"checkid":001,"checkData":{"diagnosticsData":{"troubleSource":0,"data":"[2020-01-01 16:00:53.707961][[lat[0]][long[0]][alt[0]][canbetrust[0]][mars[0]]][signal[5]][TEM2 wake up]"}}}}}
" as an value. Doing this I was able to populate the payload before encoding it the same way as earlier mentioned

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. There is [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) available via [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) plugin bundle installable using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
3. If you CSV file has references to other JMeter Functions or Variables you can resolve them by wrapping into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

   - to read the file:

     ```
     ${__FileToString(somefile.csv,,)}
     ```
   - to read the file and resolve any functions or variables in it:

     ```
     ${__eval( ${__FileToString(somefile.csv,,)})
     ```
   - to read the file, resolve any functions or variables and Base64-encode the result:

     ```
     ${__base64Encode(${__eval( ${__FileToString(somefile.csv,,)})},)}
     ```

   Demo:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T for helping me improve my solution by supplying various solutions. I chose the __base64Encode() function in my solution.